# fit nodes inside part of multipart shape (TikZ)

Tags: tikz-pgf, fit

Is it possible to use the `fit` library to fit nodes only inside the the second half?

## MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart, fit}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick,
        dot/.style={fill=blue,circle,minimum size=3pt}]


        \node[dot] (a) at (1,1) {};
        \node[dot] (b) at (2,2) {};
        \node[dot] (c) at (1,2) {};

        \node[draw, rectangle split, 
            rectangle split parts=2,fit=(a) (b) (c)]
            {points: \nodepart{second}};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Result

[image: result]

## Hoping for

[image: what I'm looking for]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative remains using `fit` library. The first fit simply includes nodes (a),(b),(c) and does not draw the frame. The second fit, with draw, then encompasses text and (a),(b),(c)

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart, fit}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick,
        dot/.style={fill=blue,circle,minimum size=3pt}]
        \node[dot] (a) at (1,1) {};
        \node[dot] (b) at (2,2) {};
        \node[dot] (c) at (1,2) {};
        \node[fit=(a) (b) (c), inner sep=0.2cm] (d) {};
        \draw (d.north west) -- (d.north east);
        \node[anchor=south, at=(d.north) ] (e) {Points:};                  
        \node[draw, fit=(a) (b) (c) (e), inner sep=0.2cm, rectangle, rounded corners]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use nested `tikzpicture`s:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \node[draw, rectangle split, 
            rectangle split parts=2]
            {points: \nodepart{second}
                \begin{tikzpicture}[thick,
                    dot/.style={fill=blue,circle,minimum size=3pt}]
                    \node[dot] (a) at (1,1) {};
                    \node[dot] (b) at (2,2) {};
                    \node[dot] (c) at (1,2) {};
                \end{tikzpicture}
             };

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I prefer to use nested pictures in these cases as opposed to `fit` since in this way you effectively define a "module" so rearranging/transforming the block is easier. With `fit`, to move the whole block you have to move the contents, with nested pictures you just move the outer node.